# Two UI small glitches. Please confirm

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, design

The red circled links don't work, and the blue circled box is superimposed.

I am not tagging it as a "bug" yet since I suspect there may be some cache problem somewhere in my upstream internet proxy chain.

Please confirm.

[image]

Comment: The links work for me and the `Ask Question` is in the right place. For future: the [meta-tag:design] tag is Jin's bat signal :) He'll probably be around more frequently the next few days since we just graduated

Comment: @R.M Ok. Thanks! I'll wait one more confirmation and I will delete the question.

Comment: It's helpful, when you report stuff like this, to also include the browser and OS versions you're using (Based on the logs, think you're using Firefox 12 on Windows XP...)

Comment: @Shog9 Yep. That is it.

Comment: I can see the blue circled item is definitely a glitch, which has been reported. What's wrong with the sub nav, circled in red?

Comment: @Jin Re: red circled links. They are not working as links (omm> "on my machine")

Comment: @belisarius I see. I believe the fix for "Ask Question"  will fix that too. The top nav's parent div was probably covering it.

Comment: @Jin Tested at 100% mag. and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The "Ask Question" link being off is definitely a glitch. A fix will be in the next production build.

Comment: The *active* *hot* *week* *month* buttons break (apparently) because of the **Ask Question** wrap.